# Field hints and tips?

Tags: field-recording, sound-design, equipment, nature-recording, ambience

I have taken the plunge and bought a sound devices 788T with SSD and CL8.
Also a M/S rig consisting of Senn. MKH40/30 combination.
I would love any hints or tips re cabling, bags, tripods, stands.. etc.. all the wee things I dont want to discover I've left out when I arrive at the first port of call!
Here is the rig as it stands.
SD788T SSD with CL8
BK 4006 omnis x2
Telinga Parabola with stereo dat mic.
Sennheiser 416 and ME66
Sennheiser MKH 40/30
JRF hydrophones C series x2
JRF Contact mics C series x2
Various necessary Rycote baskets, windgags and softies..Carbon Boom.
Manfrotto and gitzo carbon tripods.

If there's any hints and tips anyone can give or any glaring ommissions.. please let me know.
I'm stepping into unfamiliar territory.. the great outdoors. How do I keep the gear dry  etc..? quiet clothing? any favourites? backpacks.. audio bags.. all hints and tips gratefully received.
Many thanks,

Phil.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, you're gonna need some cables to use all that stuff. ;)

I would suggest looking into decent bag for your recorder. I'm very fond of [Petrol bags](http://www.petrolbags.com/Sound-Bags) myself. I'd also suggest grabbing a few extra NP-type camcorder batteries and two chargers to carry around with you. The last thing you want is to run out of power. If you've got the chargers with you, you can start recharging a battery as soon as you swap it out.

Another useful item to have is a bunch of [velcro straps](http://www.homedepot.com/h_d1/N-5yc1v/R-202261940/h_d2/ProductDisplay?catalogId=10053&langId=-1&keyword=velcro&storeId=10051) for cable management.

Comment: THanks @shaun, got a bag and cables sorted.. batteries and 1 charger too. I checked out the Petrol bags.. I like the look of them. I bought portabrace, but may have a look at some of petrol's other gear. Will also look into getting another charger. Good idea!

Answer (score 1):

These two threads will provide you with a lot of great ideas.  All the stuff you might need but won't find in an audio shop.

[What non-standard gear is an important part of your kit](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/8017/what-non-standard-gear-is-an-important-part-of-your-kit)

[What are the small bits in your field recording bag?](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/252/what-are-the-small-bits-in-your-field-recording-bag)

Comment: Cheers @azimuth I'll check this all out!
Phil.

Answer (score 0):

Phil,

Seems like you've been well advised on the equipment choice

The only things I would add are:

Headphones e.g. Sennheiser HD25

And backup gear :

I run 2x SD702s which can be sync'd or run independently - perhaps a small recorder like a Olympus LS-100 would do as a fall back.

A spare pair of headphones or at least ipod earbuds.

An AC + 12V car charger for the SD's NP batteries - I normally use two of these as they are smaller than the SD PSU

I'm not sure if Tiso sells them but I found some rubber coated formable cable tidies that are great for holding cables bundles or to stop cables flapping against the tripod - [gear ties](http://www.niteize.com/collections/gear-tie)

There is also a knowledgable bunch of people on the [Yahoo Nature recordists group](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/naturerecordists/)